# How to display user defined message on the browser after blocking website using hosts

Tags: browser, hosts-file

I am using the `hosts` file for blocking websites, and when we try to open that website the browser shows some default message, but I need to display my own message.

Is there any possibility for displaying a user-defined message?

Comment: Of course, [a `hosts` file is the wrong tool for this job](http://superuser.com/a/360437/38062) …

Answer (score 1):

Run a web-server on your local machine on the usual port (80) and set a custom error page

In your hosts file use 127.0.0.1 as the address for blocked domains

---

Update:

If you have [Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com) installed, you can use something like this (start it from a command prompt)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Daemon;
use HTTP::Status;

my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new(LocalPort => 80);

while (my $c = $d->accept) {
    while (my $r = $c->get_request) {
       $c->send_file_response("./blocked.html");
    }
    $c->close;
    undef($c);
}
```

Other scripting languages are available. Batteries not included.

Comment: how to run web-server on port (80),. Can you please explain clearly

Comment: @vijayP: First [select a simple web server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ltwebserv/). If you are a Windows user, you might want to use IIS. Second, read it's documentation. Third, if you can't see how to set a custom page for 404 errors, ask here (or maybe in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @vijayP: Answer updated